# Prove that there exist's biggest integer such that k<x $x\in R $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers, integers

I am studying real Analysis from Rudin's book.So i dont skip any "obvious" to Rudin sentences.So somewhere in chapter 1 says.  $x$ real number .Suppose $n$ the biggest integer  $n \leq x $ .So i wanted to prove there exists something like that.Using only the info i have so far.

Proof.

I took the set. $A=$ all integers $n\leq x $
From  Archimedean  property there exists z(integer)>x so we have an upper bound.

Since R has the least upper bound property there exists a supremum. So now only left is to prove that

$SupA$  $\exists$   $A $

So that $A$ has a maximum. Suppose $supA$ does not belong in $A$ so $supA>x$ . I want to use the definition of the supremum  but if i take $supA -1$ or something else it doesnt mean that $supA-a$ belongs to S since $supA$ is a real number (might not be but i cant be sure) the least upper bound property is in R not Z.Unless i prove the least upper bound property for Z.So im stuck as to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A = \{n \in \mathbb N : n \le x\}$, you don't need the Archimedean property to find an upper bound of $A$: $x$ itself is an upper bound.

Since $\sup A$ is the supremum of $A$, $\sup A - 1$ is not an upper bound of $A$. Thus there exists $n \in A$ with the property that $\sup A - 1 < n$.

In turn this means $\sup A < n+1$ so that $n+1 \notin A$. Thus $n+1 > x$.

Consequently $n$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: you used a definition that n is the largest integer less than x if n<x<n+1 right?. I want to prove that  SupA belongs to the set.

Comment: Well, $n$ is in the set and $n+1$ isn't. Is it possible for any element of $A$ to lie in between $n$ and $n+1$?